# Launchd script that edits its own schedule not working

Tags: launchd, plist, macos

I have 2 launchd plists that are basically entirely identical, save for the <StartInterval> settings. Both plists simply launch a shell script and redirects both stdout and stderr to files for me to inspect later. The shell script is supposed to reschedule the launchd job that launches it to the second plist file. The content of the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date) >> /Users/administrator/executionTime.txt # Just to make sure the scheduling is working
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.test_schedule.plist
sudo cp -f /Users/administrator/com.example.test_schedule_2.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.test_schedule.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.test_schedule.plist
```

The problem I'm running into right now - it seems like the script runs up to the `unload` line (the execution time is appended to the txt file, and the launchd job is gone) and then mysteriously stops for some reason. I've resorted to inserting `echo` lines between each statement to confirm, and that's exactly what it seems like - an `echo` before the `unload` line prints to the redirected stdout file, but an `echo` after the `unload` does not print. I'm really not sure what could be the problem here? Is it permission-related?

Comment: I'm tired and my brain may not be working properly, so I apologize if I'm misunderstanding. I think that the job is unloading itself, and thus the script stops right after the `unload`. The solution would be to have two jobs, one which loads and unloads the other. You say you already have two jobs, so I apologize if you're already doing this (hence the "I'm tired" caveat), but regardless I would make absolutely sure that `JobA` is unloading `JobB`, and not `JobA` (itself).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I think you're right, I don't actually have 2 jobs right now, I have 1 job that's trying to unload itself and load a different plist to reschedule. That's clearly not going to work. I'll think about having a second job to do the unload